# Visual Studio: Create code snippet, including method invocation

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a `todo` code snippet in the form of: `" // Todo [UserName, DateTime]"`. How can I create this one via `Visual Studio` Code Snippets? I know how I basically create a snippet. But I don't know how to perform method invocation (e.g. `DateTime.UtcNow`) in a snippet.

Comment: Have you done any research at all?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14786/Automatic-variable-replacement-in-Visual-Studio-co). Unfortunately there is no automatic variable replacement in VS. Seems a bit hackish to me

Comment: Also it seems like, as you adding a comment, VisualStudio wont navigate to your defined Parameters. Usually you should find the existing snippets at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1031\Visual C#`. Maybe you find something inspiring there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lokusking stated there is no actual variable replacement in VS2015.